# syntax error at or near "SERIAL" with autoIncrement only

Tags: javascript, angularjs, postgresql, sequelize.js

I get the error on build :

> Server failed to start due to error: SequelizeDatabaseError: syntax
>   error at or near "SERIAL"

This error ONLY appears when the parameter autoIncrement=true is given to the primary key.

```
'use strict';

export default function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('Ladder', {
    ladder_id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true //<------- If commented it works fine
    },
    ladder_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    ladder_description: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: true
    },
    ladder_open: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false
    },
    ladder_hidden: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false
    },
    ladder_creation_date: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false
    },
    ladder_fk_user: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    ladder_fk_game: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      allowNull: false
    },
    ladder_fk_platforms: {
      type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.UUID),
      allowNull: false
    }

  },
    {
      schema: 'ladder',
      tableName: 'ladders'
    });
}
```

I have Sequelize 3.30.4 and postgreSQL 9.6.

I want autoIncrement at true because I am generating the UUID with postgreSQL uuid_generate_v4().

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not a regular sequelize user here but let me point out that using autoIncrement for non sequential column is not the right way in postgreql. Postgresql does not provide a default uuid number generator but an extension can be added easily https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/uuid-ossp.html. I believev you have already done so.

The next step then is to us the [sequelize.fn](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#static-method-fn) function.

> Creates an object representing a database function. This can be used
>   in search queries, both in where and order parts, and as default
>   values in column definitions.

so we have

```
ladder_id: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
    default: sequelize.fn('uuid_generate_v4')
}
```

Comment: So if I get that right you cannot tell Sequelize to let PostgreSQL generate the UUID through the default value configured when I created the table ?

Comment: no this is what it does. passes a call to the postgresql generator. That's what sequelize.fn does

Comment: Yes but sequelize passes himself the call. He doesn't use the default value configurated in PostgreSQL.
But I know what to do now. Thank you.

Comment: glad it helped.  all the best with your project

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that `autoIncrement` for PostgreSQL is hardcoded to use SERIAL type for column and this conflicts with your choice of UUID.

Try removing autoincrement parameter and instead use defaultvalue:

```
return sequelize.define('Ladder', {
    ladder_id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      defaultValue: UUIDV4
    },
```

Comment: But that would make Sequelize generate the UUID. The thing is that I want postgreSQL to take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
child_id: {
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
},
parent_id: {
    references: {
        model: 'parent',
        key: 'parent_id'
    },
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
}
```

Comment: Just a tip: generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.